# getting error Invalid password in django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-login

Hi Everyone i am creating login api in drf but getting error  invalid password, in my db password save as hash mode, when i remove hash mode then getting error in token section, please help me out.

**models.py**

```
class GmsUser(GmsBaseModel):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    middle_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "gms_users"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

**serializer.py**

```
class GmsUserSignupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GmsUser
        fields = '__all__'
    
    validate_password= make_password
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def gms_user_login(request):
    user_name = request.data.get("user_name")
    password = request.data.get("password")
    if user_name is None or password is None:
        return Response({'detail': 'Please provide both username and password'})
    else:
        try:
            user=GmsUser.objects.get(user_name=user_name)
        except GmsUser.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'detail': 'UserName Invalid Credentials'})
        if user.password.lower() != password.lower():
            return Response({'detail': 'Password Invalid Credentials'})
        else:
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return Response({'token': token.key})
```

**this is custom model token based auth. for drf**

```
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def loginapi(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        user = authenticate(
            request,
            username=data['username'],
            password=data['password']
        )
        # print(user)
        users=User.objects.filter(username=data['username']).values_list('id',flat=True)
        query=Team.objects.filter(managers=users[0]).exists()
        team_name=Team.objects.filter(managers=users[0]).values_list('id',flat=True)
        city_id=Team.objects.filter(managers=users[0]).values_list('city_id',flat=True)
        if user is None:
            return JsonResponse({'error':'unable to login'}, status=400)
        else:
            try:
                if query:
                    token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
                    return JsonResponse({'token': token.key,'team':list(team_name),'manager_id':list(users),'city_id':list(city_id)}, status=201)
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({'error':'User does not exist in Team'}, status=400)
                
            except Token.DoesNotExist:
                token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
                return JsonResponse({'token': str(token),'team':list(team_name),'manager_id':list(users),'city_id':list(city_id)}, status=200)
```

Comment: why don't you use django AbstractUser model to create your custom user table

Comment: @ShishirSubedi because i used custom user model for different app, one project have multiple app and different requirement, that's why i need to create new user model

Comment: could you please show me the current error?

Comment: @KarishmaUpadhyay can you attach other code snippet like for Token model and so